# Finding entry in 'different places' when navigating an implicit binary search tree

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

So I created an implicit binary tree, and a simple way of navigating through that tree that reacts when, for example, you push the left arrow, right arrow, or up arrow:

```
var items = [ .... ];

function newItem() {
    var me = this;
    this.item_location = 1;

    this.leftItem = function() {
        var left = items[(me.item_location * 2)];
        if(left){
             me.theItem = //create element, insert item from 'left' var, display item
             me.item_location *= 2;
        } else {}
    }

    this.rightItem = function() {
        var right = items[(me.item_location * 2) + 1];
        if(right){
            me.theItem = //create element, insert item from 'right' var, display item
            me.item_location = (me.item_location * 2) + 1;
        } else {}

    this.upItem = function() {
        var up = items[Math.floor(me.item_location / 2)];
        if(up){
            me.theItem = //as above
            me.item_location = Math.floor(me.item_location / 2);
    } else {
        // abandon setting this item, return to a different context/menu
    }
}
```

My issue is that I'm finding 'duplicates' that aren't actually there, so there must be a bug in either this tree navigation code or in the code I'm using to check for duplicates:

```
function findItem(theItem) {
    var itemLocations = [];

    for(var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(items[i] === theItem) {
            itemLocations.push(i);
        }
    }

    for(var i = itemLocations.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(itemLocations[i]);
    }

    console.log(itemLocations);

    return itemLocations;
}
```

What is wrong with this? It's consistently ending up with certain entries showing up twice, but the findItem function consistently finds only one entry.

There's nothing more to the code that could possibly cause this, so I feel like I've missed something super obvious.

Comment: can you add some data to make the code runnable?

Comment: Good idea, sorry, I'll get on this in about an hour or so. I'll generate numbers from 0->32000->64000 and put them in the appropriate order in items[].

edit: I can't share the actual data I'm using for various reasons, hopefully this is good enough.

Comment: please add some simplified data to the question to get a kind of sense of how the data is organised.

Comment: I'll be able to do this in about an hour or so, thanks for the suggestion ^ ^^

Comment: Hmm, life is happening. I don't have time to do it now after all, sorry. For now, all I can do is repeat that it's an implicit binary search tree, with all that that entails - i.e. it is an array sorted such that 2i corresponds with a left node on a binary tree and 2i + 1 corresponds with a right node. I will come back to this as soon as possible with some usable data.

Comment: please add a small example of `items`.